# Powershell script to initialize new drives, naming them from array

Tags: powershell

I drummed up the following code to initialize new disks that are added to a Windows VM:

```
 $newdisk = get-disk | where partitionstyle -eq 'raw'

foreach ($d in $newdisk){
$disknum = $d.Number
$dl = get-Disk $d.Number | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
Format-Volume -driveletter $dl.Driveletter -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "Disk $disknum" -Confirm:$false
}
```

Instead of using the disk number for the file system label, I want to use some predefined volume names, like "OS", "Data", "System", etc....

I tried $name = "OS", "Data", "System" and put that variable in place of $disknum, but that just added the whole string as the volume name as it looped through.

Am I missing something? Should it be a variable inside of the loop? How can I get it to read each name from the variable for each run of the disk initilization inside the loop ?

I am newish to powershell and seeing examples helps me quite a bit.

Comment: you need to have some criteria by which the volume labels can be assigned to a drive....in other words how do you determine that a particular drive is to be an OS and another data?

Comment: Does not matter in this case, I just need to names to be assigned to each drive. This might have been a bad example, the OS drive will initialized and named before the script it run, so whatever drives are left should just get Data and System assigned to them in whatever was it loops through them. Does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i do not know how many drives you are working with i included some dummy entries in the `labels` array.

this uses a for loop instead of a foreach thus preventing the need for a nested loop structure.

```
$newdisk = @(get-disk | Where-Object partitionstyle -eq 'raw')
$Labels = @('OS','Data','System','OS','Data','System')

for($i = 0; $i -lt $newdisk.Count ; $i++)
{

    $disknum = $newdisk[$i].Number
    $dl = get-Disk $disknum | 
       Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru | 
          New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
    Format-Volume -driveletter $dl.Driveletter -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel $Labels[$i] -Confirm:$false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can initialize disk based on the size of the attached disk.
2. In a scenario when you attach so many disks, you may want to attribute a specific letter to a disk based on it's size.
   #in this scenario, we will attribute letter F to a 20GB disk.

```
$disknum = @(get-disk | Where-Object partitionstyle -eq 'raw'| Where-Object {$_.Size /1GB -match '20'})
$dl = get-Disk $disknum.Number | 
Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
Format-Volume -driveletter F -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'DB Data' -Confirm:$false
```